# Casting error on EF Core when calling stored proc on MySQL (using Pomelo)

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, ef-core-2.2, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I have a problem in a .Net Core 2.2 Web API using EF Core. I am calling a stored procedure on a MySQL database (I'm using Pomelo 2.1.4).

It's complaining about not being able to convert from DbNull to String:

> **Error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type
>   'System.String'.**   at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetString(Int32 ordinal) in
>   C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlDataReader.cs:line
>   210    at lambda_method(Closure , DbDataReader )    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.TypedRelationalValueBufferFactory.Create(DbDataReader
>   dataReader)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext
>   _, Boolean buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState
>   state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNext(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.SelectEnumerableAsyncIterator`2.MoveNextCore(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) in
>   D:\a\1\s\Ix.NET\Source\System.Interactive.Async\Select.cs:line 106
>
>   at
>   System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.AsyncIterator`1.MoveNext(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) in
>   D:\a\1\s\Ix.NET\Source\System.Interactive.Async\AsyncIterator.cs:line
>   98    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.Aggregate_[TSource,TAccumulate,TResult](IAsyncEnumerable`1
>   source, TAccumulate seed, Func`3 accumulator, Func`2 resultSelector,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken) in
>   D:\a\1\s\Ix.NET\Source\System.Interactive.Async\Aggregate.cs:line 120 
>   at
>   PropWorx.API.Controllers.FileActivitiesController.GetFileActivities(Int32
>   fileId, String fromDate, String toDate) in
>   C:\Users\fabsr\source\repos\PropWorx.API\PropWorx.API\Controllers\FileActivitiesController.cs:line
>   101    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper
>   mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[]
>   arguments)    at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
>   next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next,
>   Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   httpContext)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   httpContext)    at
>   PropWorx.API.Middlewares.TenantIdentifier.Invoke(HttpContext
>   httpContext, SharedContext sharedContext) in
>   C:\Users\fabsr\source\repos\PropWorx.API\PropWorx.API\Middlewares\TenantIdentifier.cs:line
>   73    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   httpContext)    at
>   Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)

The problem line is:

```
List<FileActivity> fileActivities = await _context.FileActivities.FromSql("CALL file_activity_procedure(@fromDate, @toDate, @fileId)", param1, param2, param3).ToListAsync();
```

the FileActivity model is:

```
public class FileActivity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    public int FileId { get; set; }
    public string FileNumber { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public int? RecordId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string TypeInfo { get; set; }
    public decimal? Debit { get; set; }
    public decimal? Credit { get; set; }
    public string AddedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? AddedDate { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
}
```

And finally, the mapping in the DbContext is:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<FileActivity>(entity =>
{
    entity.Property(e => e.Id)
        .HasColumnName("ID")
        .HasColumnType("int(11)");

    entity.Property(e => e.Date)
        .HasColumnName("Date")
        .HasColumnType("datetime");

    entity.Property(e => e.FileId)
        .HasColumnName("file_id")
        .HasColumnType("int(11)");

    entity.Property(e => e.FileNumber)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasColumnName("file_num")
        .HasColumnType("varchar(50)");

    entity.Property(e => e.Description)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasColumnName("description")
        .HasColumnType("varchar(255)");

    entity.Property(e => e.Type)
        .HasColumnName("type")
        .HasColumnType("varchar(255)");

    entity.Property(e => e.TypeInfo)
        .HasColumnName("type_info")
        .HasColumnType("varchar(255)");

    entity.Property(e => e.Debit)
       .HasColumnName("Debit")
       .HasColumnType("decimal(13,4)")
       .HasDefaultValueSql("'0.0000'");

    entity.Property(e => e.Credit)
       .HasColumnName("Credit")
       .HasColumnType("decimal(13,4)")
       .HasDefaultValueSql("'0.0000'");

    entity.Property(e => e.RecordId)
       .HasColumnName("record_id")
       .HasColumnType("int(11)");

    entity.Property(e => e.AddedBy)
        .HasColumnName("Added_By")
        .HasColumnType("varchar(45)");

    entity.Property(e => e.AddedDate)
        .HasColumnName("added_date")
        .HasColumnType("datetime");

    entity.Property(e => e.Comments)
        .HasColumnName("comment")
        .HasColumnType("text");
});
```

I've been wrecking my brain all day to try and figure this one out... Any ideas?

Comment: I would check if the SP returns DbNull for some of the string columns marked as required ("file_num" or "description"). Or comment out `IsRequired` from the fluent mapping and see if it works.

Comment: I can't believe I'm such an idiot! How did I not see that! Thank you so much Ivan!

Comment: P.s. I'd like to mark your reply as an answer, but I can't as it's a comment? Don't know if you'd maybe like to post it as a reply so I can mark it as the answer?... .Thanks again

Comment: You are welcome, glad it helped :) But it was just a guess (shot in the dark), hence comment. Feel free to post a self answer what was the issue and how you resolved it, and I'll be happy to vote it up. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

As Ivan mentioned in the comment, the "description" and "file_num" fields were required (IsRequired = true). Because some of the rows had DbNulls, it caused an exception. I removed that restriction and all was fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that those properties that are not required in modelBuilder must be defined nullable in your entities and models with ?. Like FileId and it is because if there is a record in the table with a null value for those fields then it will return null in your entity class but your entity class can not accept a null value for those not nullable properties and then it will throw an error.